# How can I change the ingredients in the recipe to correspond with the user input?

Tags: javascript, html

**Background**
My code is focused on cooking (Banana Bread recipe). Depending on the number of people, I will sometimes make two Banana Bread's as opposed to one. Yet, when I coded my recipe, all of the ingredients in the HTML were corresponding to one Banana Bread. Thus, when I cook two banana breads, I accidentally use the amount of ingredients that is used for one banana bread. I want to create a drop down menu that will change the ingredient quantity.

**Example**
If 1 was selected, it would say 2 cups flour, 1/2 tsp salt.
If 2 was selected, it would say 4 cups flour, 1 tsp salt.
If 3 was selected, it would say 6 cups flour, 1 1/2 tsp salt.

**Code**

```js
// Step 1: Find the element we want the event on
var button = document.getElementById("button");


// Step 2: Define the event listener function
var onButtonClick = function() {
  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
  var selection = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  if(selection === 'a')
  {
    document.getElementById('n1').value = n1;
  }

  if(selection === 'b')
  {
    document.getElementById('n1').value = n1*2;
  }

  if(selection === 'c')
  {
    document.getElementById('n1').value = n1*3;
  }

  // Step 3: Attach event listener to element
  button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
}
```

```html
<!-- Question -->
<label> How many Banana Bread's are you making? </label>


<!-- Selection -->
<select id="quantity">
  <option value="a">1</option>
  <option value="b">2</option>
  <option value="c">3</option>
</select><br><br>


<!-- Button -->
<button id="button" type="button">Let's get started!</button><br><br>


<!-- HTML Recipe -->
<p>Step 1: Add <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and <span id="amount"> &frac12;</span> tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.</p>
```

Comment: Why is the event listener inside the function it is supposed to call?

Comment: Where is the HTML element with `id` = "n1"? You might mean `amount` in this case, but you have more than one element with that `id`. `id`s should be unique

Answer (score 0):

On this section you have to change your id for the 1/2 to something different. In my example I just changed the id to amount2.

`<p>
Step 1: Add <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and <span id="amount2"> &frac12;</span> tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.
 </p>`

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick(){
  document.getElementById("amount").innerText = 2;
  document.getElementById("amount2").innerText = 1/2;
  var n1 = document.getElementById("amount").innerText;
  var n2 = document.getElementById("amount2").innerText;
  var selection = document.getElementById("quantity").value;

  if (selection === 'a') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerText = n2;
  }

  if (selection === 'b') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1*2;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerText = n2*2;
  }

  if (selection === 'c') {
    document.getElementById('amount').innerText = n1*3;
    document.getElementById('amount2').innerText = n2*3
  }
}
```

This should work for what you need for switching between the correct cups of flour and tsp of salt based on the number chosen from your drop down. I do not know an easy way to keep your tsp of salt as a fraction when showing in your display so in this example I go to decimal when used.

Comment: Thank you Runemonster. If I had 25 ingredients, would I have to create 25 different ID's (eg, amount1, amount2...amount25) or is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Yes you would have to create 25 IDs.I do not think their is an easy way to simplify this, because your staring amount for each ingredient would be different meaning you would not be able to write a loop to change them. You would need to know the starting amount of each value before hand and then you would be able to times that value by the drop down list. Without that they all would be changed to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
 <label>How many Banana Bread's are you making? </label>

 <select id="quantity">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
 </select><br><br>

 <button id="button" type="button">
  Let's get started!
 </button>

 <p>
  Step 1: Add
  <span id="amount">2</span> cups flour and
  <span id="amount2">1</span>
  / 2 tsp salt into a large, dry bowl.
 </p>

 <script>
 var button = document.getElementById("button");

 var onButtonClick = function() {
  var selection = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  const breadsQuantity = parseInt(selection, 10);

  document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = breadsQuantity * 2;
        document.getElementById('amount2').innerHTML = breadsQuantity;
 }

    button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Nico Diz. It worked for the flour, but it did not convert the salt fraction (ie, 1/2 tsp salt). Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Pulvinar, I updated the snippet. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Nico, would you happen to know how you can prevent the fraction from being converted into a decimal?

Comment: No, I don't.   Anyway, in this example I did not use a fraction. Instead, the #amount2 has the value selected as the HTML text (changes dyamically when click `Let's get started`). Then, out of #amount2, the text continues with `/ 2 tsp salt...`.